# How to show categories and sub categories in view page and select menu in zend frame work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i'm having the table like

category_id category_name   parent_id 
1           General Grocery   0
2            Ready to eat     0
3               rice          1
4               oils          1
5             flour           1
6            seed             1
7          testing cate       0
8           testing           5

i want to display the categories with "n" number of sub categories in subcategories. My main moto is by using the array generated by the code i want to display in view page and the select menu in the zend form. I found the code in php. but i'm unable to use that in zend. Can some one help me out with this please. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to generate a tree.. so there are two known patterens to me

- adjacency level pattern
- Nested Level Patteren

I suggest you to use Nexted level pattern

If you follow the given below two links you will surely come to know what to do.

- http://blog.richardknop.com/2009/05/nested-set-model/
- http://baobab.sideralis.org/

By this you can generate appropriate tree. now you have to generate a tree in which you can select your items. so you should use this tree http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/index.shtml

you can keep checkboxes to select the items and store in the database